# How is "pertain" used?

Tags: word-usage

Which one is correct?

> This part is pertaining to server.

> This part is pertained to server.

Should I use *with* instead of *to* in the examples?

I tried an online spellchecker, which it told me I should replace *pertain* with *concern*. Should I listen to it?

I want to say server will handle that part, or that part is done by server.

Comment: Since you already know how to use *handle* and *done* in this context, just use one of those and concentrate on using the definite article correctly. *"This part is **handled/done** by **the** server."*

Comment: Thanks Bob ! The reason I'm using these words instead of simple ones is that I am writing a formal article and in this section there are a lot of parts of a system which each of them handled by a specified part. So I need a lot words to prevent the article from getting boring. Thank YOU!@

Comment: It's not *poetry!* Particularly in a formal context, where clarity is more important than entertaining your reader and not boring him, you should use simple words that you *do* understand. This would be a relatively uncommon way to use *pertains* (or *concerns*) - they're more often used in contexts with the sense *is of interest/relevance to [something]*, which doesn't sit well with a pile of inanimate tin such as ***the*** server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. 'This part is pertaining to the server' is correct -- better yet, use 'this part pertains to the server'
2. Do not use 'with' - BobRodes explained that well
3. Pertain and Concern can both be used here - but you would say 'This part concerns the server' or 'this part pertains to the server' -- Personally, I would use concerns
4. Here are two sentences:

This paragraph concerns the server
 -- That sentence means: 'This paragraph is written about the server'

The server handles this paragraph
--  That sentence means: 'The server controlls or otherwise does something to the paragraph'

Answer (score 1):

I would say "This part pertains to the server."  You don't need "is pertaining" because this is more a state of being than an ongoing action.  You wouldn't use the passive voice.  You shouldn't use "with"; "to" is correct.  I wouldn't change the word to *concerned*.